# execvp and type of parameters - ansi c

Tags: c, strtok, argv, execvp

I am having trouble with using `execvp()`. `execvp()` expects type **char * const*** as second parameter. I want to parse arguments passed to application (in `argv`) and make an array of that type. For example, user is invoking the binary as given below:

```
./myapp "ls -a -l"
```

And then I make the below array from it:

```
{"ls", "-a", "-l", NULL}
```

Now, my code looks like:

```
    const char* p[10];
    char temp[255] = "ls -a -l";

    p[0] = strtok(temp, " ");
    for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
        if( p[i] != NULL ) {
            p[i+1] = strtok(NULL, " ");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

It works, but I am getting the warning:

`main.c:47: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘execvp’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/unistd.h:573: note: expected ‘char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘const char **’`

How to do it **correctly**?

Comment: Where in the code are you calling `execvp()` ? What is `test` variable doing in `strtok()` where I guess `temp` variable should be. Where have you defined the `test` variable?

Comment: Of course test is a temp, i just written it for example. im calling execvp(p[0], p)... problem is in type of p.

Comment: BTW: your loop-logic is buggy. If there happen to be 9 or more tokens in the input string, the p[] array will not have a final NULL pointer.

Comment: Ofc i know it. Its just an example. In my code i will use malloc/realloc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `char *p[10]`.

To break it down: `char *const *p` means "nonconstant pointer to constant pointer of nonconstant char" -- that is, `p` is writable, `p[0]` is not writable, and `p[0][0]` is writable.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if it is safe?

Comment: Yes. Per the POSIX 2008 spec, none of the `exec` functions will write to the strings; `char *const*` is used for compatibility (instead of the more correct `const char *const*`).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the second parameter of `execvp` is a `char * const *`, which is a "pointer to a constant pointer to *non-constant* data".  You're trying to pass it a `const char **`, which is a "pointer to a pointer to *constant* data".

The way to fix this is to use `char **` instead of `const char **` (since "pointer to X" is always allowed to be convert to "pointer to `const` X", for any type X (but *only* at the top level of pointers):

```
char* p[10];
p[0] = ...;
// etc.
```

Note that if you do need to insert `const char *` parameters, you can cast them `char *` as long as you don't modify them.  Although the arguments to the `exec*` family of functions are declared as non-`const`, they won't ever modify them (see the [POSIX 2008 specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html#tag_16_111)).  The rationale there explains why they are declared as non-`const`.

Comment: Wow, great answer to an unexpectedly perplexing question. Thanks for the POSIX reference or else this reasonable absurdity would have seemed wholly unreasonable!